# Issues installing pbrt-v3 on Windows

Tags: windows, cmake, pbrt

I tried to install pbrt-v3 on my laptop but it didn't work. I used the README commands with a virtual ubuntu bash. The CMake et make did well but I can't use `pbrt` neither open a scene with it:

```
pbrt killeroo-simble.pbrt
command not found: pbrt
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: When I do this, it asks for one of the following packages: 'prt', 'python3-pbr' or 'python-pbr'.

Comment: Did you run 'make install'?

Comment: Were you able to solve it? I'm having the same problem now : (

Answer (score 0):

Clone the pbrt-v3 sourcecode:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/mmp/pbrt-v3/
```

Install a C++ compiler:

```
sudo su
[enter password]
apt-get update
apt-get install g++
```

Setup project with CMake and build it

```
cmake pbrt-v3/
cmake --build .
```

Now you should have your own build pbrt executable